# Nakdimon Ben Gurion real name

Tags: tisha-bav, maseches-gitin, masechet-taanis

The first Rash"i in Masechet Taanis (20a) says that Nakdimon Ben Gurion's real name was Boni. How did Rash"i know that, is there any earlier source for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little further down the daf (about half way, Taanis 20a)

> תָּנָא לֹא נַקְדִּימוֹן שְׁמוֹ אֶלָּא בּוּנִי שְׁמוֹ וְלָמָּה נִקְרָא שְׁמוֹ נַקְדִּימוֹן שֶׁנִּקְדְּרָה חַמָּה בַּעֲבוּרוֹ

> A Sage taught: Nakdimon was not his real name; rather his name was Buni. And why was he called Nakdimon? Because the sun broke through [nikdera] for him.